# Android WebView NTLM Authentication with Sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, ntlm, android

I am trying to open some Sharepoint 2019 pages with NTLM Authentication inside an Android WebView. It keeps asking for credentials and does not let me in. I contacted Chromium team about this issue but they didn't respond so i am trying here if someone else faced the same problem with me.

When i try same method with Sharepoint 2016 it works perfect but same code does not work on Sharepoint 2019. Is there something changed at the Authentication side on Sharepoint 2019?

**Edit: This case is happening when my phone language is set to Turkish. When its English its working just fine.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SharePoint mobile app for Android or mobile browser to access SharePoint 2019 pages?

Does this issue occur for lists/libraries?

About SharePoint mobile app for Android, the [official article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-mobile-app-for-android-d875654b-fb0a-4dbe-a17a-a676cf936284) says:

*"Windows authentication (NTLM) and Forms Based Authentication are supported for SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint Server 2013, also referred to as On-Premises."*

It does not mention SharePoint 2019.

Comment: Hello, i am trying to open those sharepoint pages on a WebView inside an Android app. So its basicly a Chrome engine. Also i tried to login via Sharepoint Mobile App for Android and Google Chrome for Android. And i am adding a case to my question. Its happening when my phone language is Turkish.